# Non-existence — it's isn't and does exist

Tags: riddle, word, enigmatic-puzzle, crossword-clues

1. > The middle of a line
   >   stretching for eternity in both sides,
   >   in words
   >   **I** am.
2. > No thing is not **me**.
   >   **Me** exists but does not live.
3. > *I* and *me*—**we**
   >   together is non-existence.

**What is *we*?**

---

### Hint(s)...

- for #1,

  > Neutral, yet negative // in words // **I** am.
- for #2,

  > You're no **me** — your dignity is way above that.
  >    Nobody is, in fact.
- for #3,

  > **I** and **me** spoon, **we** forms.
  >  Cut it, slice it, grind it into nothingness — **we** will mean the same.
  >  Well, erm, not every time, but roughly the same.
  >  Negation.
- for the entire puzzle,

  > Each bullet yields a distinct word. Don't look for multiple clues from one riddle — each riddle can only point to one word. Use logic and a bit of mathematics too.

Comment: Is the "it's" in the title a typo or intentional?

Comment: @MikeQ It's totally intentional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I** is

> **NO**.
>
> $0$ is the middle of the number line. $0$ in words is NO (as far as quantity is concerned).
>  *There are **0** apples.* $\implies$ *There are **no** apples.*
>
>  $0$ as a number is neutral, yet it's negative as in "There's *no* hope", "There's *no* apples" as opposed to "*Yes*, there is hope", "*Yes*, there are apples."

**Me** is

> **THING**. Every thing is a thing. No thing is "not a thing". No*body* is a thing. A thing is usually supposed to mean inanimate object. Things do exist but don't live.

**We** is

> **I** $+$ **me** $=$ **NOTHING**. They (I and me) *[spoon](https://www.google.com/search?q=spooning&safe=strict&rlz=1C1AOHY_enBD708BD708&tbm=isch&imgil=g5mr29Zdw2I8fM%253A%253BkzXJYtsMsYUx3M%253Bhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.buzzfeed.com%25252Fnatalyalobanova%25252Fwhat-does-your-spooning-style-say-about-you&source=iu&pf=m&fir=g5mr29Zdw2I8fM%253A%252CkzXJYtsMsYUx3M%252C_&usg=__qFcdMPfCwLH6Ihn5gF7WZbyqU_4%3D&biw=1280&bih=634&ved=0ahUKEwiZr_2r9Z_VAhUEtpQKHahcDlgQyjcIUg&ei=L9t0WdnbFYTs0gSoubnABQ#imgrc=g5mr29Zdw2I8fM:)* or in other words, join together.
>
>  
> **Nothing** doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps "I" am

> "im", the centre of "time" (note also that "im" ~= "I'm" ~= "I am")

and "me", um, is

> "possible" because if something is a thing then it must be possible

so that "we", errrm, is

> "impossible" (by combining the two).

However,

> this doesn't seem to lead to any explanation of the "it's" in the title so I will be extremely unsurprised if it's not OP's intended answer.

Note:

> im/possibility would work about as well as im/possible, and that does at least contain an "it" which might somehow lead to an explanation of the title.

Some other possibilities along similar lines (for the benefit of others, possibly including my future self, since I need to go to bed now):

> The first one might instead be the centre of "axis", so "xi" (which forms part of words like "exist" and "nonexistence", which might be useful); or "t-axis", so "x" or "axi"; or just "line", so "in". The second might be any one of many similar words -- e.g., real, actual, existing, thing -- or, taking "nothing" more literally, might be "hing". I don't see any combination of these ideas that does any better than what I have above but, e.g., we could make "in/existent" this way. If we could make the first yield "not" it would play well with "hing"; if we could make it yield "un" it would play well with "real" or "reality".

As for the (revised) title:

> the most obvious way to read it is as kinda giving away the answer: it's (i.e., the answer is) isn't (i.e., something that means roughly that) and (i.e., next to, or inserted in, or something) does exist (i.e., something that means roughly that). So e.g. if we could combine AIN'T and IS to make something suitably indicative of nonexistence, that would do. Right now, though, I don't see a way to fill the blanks so that this actually works. (And of course my interpretation may be all wrong.)

Comment: Your approach is correct, but not the final answer. You're on the right track definitely, though.

Comment: You know what to look for. Keep trying a bit more.

Comment: You're completely right about the title part. It does give away the answer. Your interpretation is absolutely correct. Go on... keep trying

Answer (score 1):

Explanation

> - Middle means **Center**.
>   - The middle of a line stretching for eternity in both sides, in words means:  **Infinite**, **Universe**.
>   - I am means **Exist**.
>   - Non existence means **doesn't exist**.
>   - We means **Universe** or **World**.

Answer

> The center of the universe exists, but infinite in real world doesn't
>  exist.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Can you explain why you think this is the answer to the question?

Comment: Wow! Very close but not it. Any line is infinite. What's the middle? Each bullet yields a distinct answer. You have to consider different riddles and not look for multiple hints in one riddle.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my guess:

> **I** is One, **Me** is Zero, and **We** is Infinity.

**I**

> The roman numeral I means one. All numbers are multiples of one.

**Me**

> Zero exists but is not a tangible thing - it is the absence of things (nothing). Hint #2 could mean "you're no zero", as in, not to think lowly of one's self.

**We**

> Divide one by zero mathematically, you get Infinity. Divide it programmatically, you get NaN (not a number - it does not exist). Hint #3 could refer to how there are different values for Infinity, but mutating it still yields Infinity (e.g.,  $\infty+1=\infty$, or $\infty+2=\infty$, and so on).

Answer (score 1):

I, me and we are:

> **Nothing.** I picked up on a bit of Nihilism straight away, I'll work on my specific answers below.

The middle of a line
stretching for eternity in both sides,
in words
I am.

> Placeholder

No thing is not me.
Me exists but does not live.

> Placeholder

I and me—we
together is non-existence.

> Placeholder

Comment: **I** is NO, **me** is THING, and **we** is NOTHING.

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine If your comment is the solution, then you may want to post (and accept) your own answer to the riddle, including the explanation.